# Unable to set file secrets passwords on docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I want to access a secret file with docker-compose. I follow many tutorials and reproduce the structure. The container is launched but when I need to log in, the right string to enter is "/run/secrets/sec_pgadmin_default_email". I want the login to be the one inside my secret file: admin. In this secret file pgadmin_default_email.txt, there is only the word admin. I don't know if the structure of this file is good. Should it be a dictionary or something else ?

```
version: '3.8' services:   pgadmin4:    
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles/
      dockerfile: dockerfile_pgadmin4 
    image: img_pgadmin
    container_name: cont_pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "80:80" 
    secrets:
      - sec_pgadmin_default_email 
      - sec_pgadmin_default_password
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=/run/secrets/sec_pgadmin_default_email
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/sec_pgadmin_default_password

secrets:   
  sec_pgadmin_default_email:
    file: ./.secrets/pgadmin_default_email.txt   
  sec_pgadmin_default_password:
    file: ./.secrets/pgadmin_default_password.txt
```

PS I just use the command `docker-compose up -d`, without swarn things or else. I don't define external secrets and I prefer not. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

the environment variable will be set to the path of the file containing the actual value. Not the actual value itself.

For example, in Go you could do something like:

```
var pgAdminDefaultEmailFile = os.Getenv("PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL") // get the file
pgAdminDefaultEmailValue, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pgAdminDefaultEmailFile) // get the value

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
pgAdminDefaultEmail = string(pgAdminDefaultEmailValue) // parse out the value
```